# Split string by backslash in Javascript

Tags: javascript, split

I have a string like this
`str = 'zone\city'`
I want to split this string by the backslash. Tried with `str.split('\\')` but it does not work.
I know backslash is not escaped in `str` String. Its the reason why i can not split. However, then I tried replace the backslash with another character but could not find any workable solution. Anyone can advise me a solution in javascript to split the above string. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `str = 'zone\city'` literal doesn't have a backslash character in it. You need to use something like `String.raw\`zone\city\`` or `"zone\\city"`

Comment: `str = 'zone\city'` is equal to `str = 'zonecity'`, try `str = 'zone\\city'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single backslash will be escaped from the string:

```js
str = 'zone\city'
console.log(str)
```

You need to escape the one in the string too:

```js
str = 'zone\\city'
console.log(str.split('\\'))
console.log(str)
```

Comment: Yes, I know this. I'm wondering how to escape this single backslash. Because I get the value from another service.

Comment: @Liam, I have already mentioned it in the description. Anyways, thank you for ur time.